# Blitting the camera frame from ARKit on MTKView

Tags: ios, camera, arkit, metal

I'm trying to blit frames coming from an `ARFrame` on an `MTKView`. For various reasons I'm trying to avoid using shaders for that. What I'm doing basically looks like:

In the `drawInMTKView` method:

```
// When the session:didUpdateFrame callback is called I create a
// CIImage from the CVPixelBufferRef inside ARFrame provided and
// set the property in the view

- (void)drawInMTKView:(nonnull MTKView *)view {
    if (!view.currentDrawable || !view.currentRenderPassDescriptor) {
        return;
    }

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];

    [ciContext render:ciImage
               toMTLTexture:mtkView.currentDrawable.texture
               commandBuffer:commandBuffer bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.drawableSize.width, view.drawableSize.height) colorSpace:colorSpace];
    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:mtkView.currentDrawable];
    [commandBuffer commit];
}
```

The problem is I can't get it to cover the whole view and it's not rotated correctly. It also breaks down when the view rotates, probably because it's trying to write outside the buffer boundaries. I tested by giving a 100x100 rectangle as the bound to the `render:toMTLTexture` method.

I'll be happy if anyone can guide me on how to render this correctly. Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: At least part of your issue is that the camera pixel buffer comes in with the sensor’s native orientation (always landscape right). `ARFrame` has a [displayTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform) method to get you at least part of the way to correct. You might also need to consider lower-left-origin vs center-origin coordinate systems.

Comment: Thank you! `displayTransformForOrientation` does what I want. I still don't know why the image gets garbled when the screen rotates but thanks anyway!